# .netcore, Razor, Device registration in www

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core, fingerprinting

I need to register user device in my service. But I really don't know how to start. I mean, I know that the keyword is "device fingerprinting", but I've found rather this as an issue, not the solution.

I would like to achieve something like in Office 365 or some banking sites.
User can register his device (first device registration will be automatically), and can also block/delete his device. So, is there any reliable algorithm or ready solution to achieve that?

I know that I can get users browser fingerprint with screen resolution, but this is not what I'm asking. I would like to be able to quite uniqally identify user's machine (taken under consideration some changes that user may do in his machine).

Comment: Browser name (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, …) + IP address?

Comment: OK, what should I do, when IP address or browser changes? Please, read my question again. Especially the last paragraph :)

Comment: What was your decided solution? Researching a solution as well.

Comment: Hi, finally I gave up with this. I think that cookie and simple fingerprinting is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple and straightforward (but not the most secure way) for 'remember me' or 'trust this device' is to [install cookies](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31327/how-to-remember-a-trusted-machine-using-two-factor-authentication-like-googles) with a nonce - an encrypted unique user and device hash code identifier. That allows your service to have the user device and browser on that device uniquely identified unless a private session is used or the browser cache is cleared. It also should allow your service to provide the user with a list of trusted devices/browsers to block unrecognized or stolen ones as it will be stored in the backend database for authentication purposes.

As discussed [here](https://gatekeeper-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it is not entirely secure since the cookies might be stolen.

[Scott Arciszewski's answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44/how-to-securely-implement-a-remember-me-feature) describes a more secure approach that uses cookies which can include [fingerprinting](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fingerprinting) you wrote you already know about.

Cookies can expire in a specified period of time without connection to your service.

Comment: You gave some interesting information, unfortunately none gives the real solution. It seems that the problem is more complicated than I thought. But with your links I think I would be able to create something.

Comment: OK, I have another problem. For now, I am using info like: OSName, Browser name, Http-Accept, screen resolution and timezone. Every feature has its own probability to change. For example timezone is more probable to change than screen resolution. Anyway, let's assume that there are two identical devices (have identical features). So what's now? Should I add some kind of guid on client computer? But this cookie should be kept forever. Is my thinking correct? Should I really add this guid?

Answer (score 1):

One option could be using [Evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie). Create unique identifier with your own algorithm for a device and store it with Evercookie.

Evercookie is a Javascript API that produces extremely persistent cookies in a browser. Its goal is to identify a client even after they've removed standard cookies, Flash cookies (Local Shared Objects or LSOs), and others.

This is accomplished by storing the cookie data on as many browser storage mechanisms as possible. If cookie data is removed from any of the storage mechanisms, evercookie aggressively re-creates it in each mechanism as long as one is still intact.

If the Flash LSO, Silverlight or Java mechanism is available, Evercookie can even propagate cookies between different browsers on the same client machine!

Client browsers must support as many of the following storage mechanisms as
possible in order for Evercookie to be effective.

- Standard [HTTP Cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)
- Flash [Local Shared Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object)
- Silverlight [Isolated Storage](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/isolatedstorage/)
- CSS [History Knocking](https://samy.pl/csshack/)
- Storing cookies in [HTTP ETags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) (Backend server required)
- Storing cookies in [Web cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache) (Backend server required)
- [HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/client-identification-mechanisms#TOC-Lower-level-protocol-identifiers) Pinning (works in Incognito mode)
- [window.name caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#window.name)
- Internet Explorer [userData storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424.aspx)
- HTML5 [Session Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute)
- HTML5 [Local Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-localstorage)
- HTML5 [Global Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#globalStorage)
- HTML5 [Database Storage via SQLite](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/)
- HTML5 Canvas - Cookie values stored in RGB data of auto-generated, force-cached PNG images (Backend server required)
- HTML5 [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)
- Java [JNLP PersistenceService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/jnlp/index.html)
- Java exploit [CVE-2013-0422](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-0422) - Attempts to escape the applet sandbox and write cookie data directly to the user's hard drive.

USAGE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="evercookie.js"></script>

<script>
var ec = new evercookie(); 

// set a cookie "id" to "12345"
// usage: ec.set(key, value)
ec.set("id", "12345"); 

// retrieve a cookie called "id" (simply)
ec.get("id", function(value) { alert("Cookie value is " + value) }); 

// or use a more advanced callback function for getting our cookie
// the cookie value is the first param
// an object containing the different storage methods
// and returned cookie values is the second parameter
function getCookie(best_candidate, all_candidates)
{
    alert("The retrieved cookie is: " + best_candidate + "\n" +
        "You can see what each storage mechanism returned " +
        "by looping through the all_candidates object.");

    for (var item in all_candidates)
        document.write("Storage mechanism " + item +
            " returned: " + all_candidates[item] + "<br>");
}
ec.get("id", getCookie); 

// we look for "candidates" based off the number of "cookies" that
// come back matching since it's possible for mismatching cookies.
// the best candidate is most likely the correct one
</script>
```

Read this post to see [how it works](https://samy.pl/evercookie/).

Comment: Well, the evercookie seems to be the best solution... but it's being blocked by browsers and can decrease my site reputation, so I would rather not use this.